# Why the verb has changed into く form

Tags: grammar, verbs

In the following sentence:

> それ以上その姿勢を続けられなくなった

Why is the verb 続けられない transformed into 続けられなく？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last component of 続けられなくなった is the verb なる, which is an intransitive verb that describes change, like “become” in English. When it is used with an い-adjective, the final い of the adjective is changed to く.

> 大き**く**なる

While 続けられない is a verb form, namely the ない-form, it conjugates the same way as い-adjectives.

Compare:

> 大き**い**
> 大き**くない**
> 大き**かった**
> 大き**くなかった**
> 大き**くて**
> 大き**ければ**

> しな**い**
> しな**くない**
> しな**かった**
> しな**くなかった**
> しな**くて**
> しな**ければ**

(I included double-negatives above just to show their forms. Don’t worry about their meanings.)

This rule applies before なる, too.

> 大き**く**なる

> しな**く**なる

The part before なる indicates the post-change state. 続けられなくなった, therefore, means that such a change happened that you are no longer able to continue (続けられない) whatever you were doing before that change.

Answer (score 3):

まずはあなたの１つ目に出てきた単語

> 続けられない

の意味をご存知でしょうか？
続けられないと言うのは「これ以上続けることが不可能」と言う意味で使われます。

そして、二個目に出てきた単語であり本題の

> 続けられなく

の意味を説明します。

意味はあなたが質問しているように「続けられなく」と単語単体の意味はほとんど同じようなですが、

今回あなたが質問しているような「**それ以上その姿勢を続けられなくなった**」と「**それ以上その姿勢を続けられない**」のように文章に当てはめて見ると少し違いが出てきます。

本来、「続けられない」と言うのは**その人の意志**でこれ以上続けることが不可能だと判断した場合に、本人がその言葉を発する、またはその状況を知っている周りの人がその人の意志を説明する場合に使います。

日常会話だと「**これ以上続けられない**よ〜だってこれ難しいもん」などの様な会話を聞いたことがありませんか？（笑）

対して「続けられなく」と言うのは**周りの状況により**続けるのが困難になった場合によく使われます。

もしくは、本人は続けたいという意思があるにも関わらず本人の体の状況もしくは他のなにかの理由でやむを得ず続けるのを取りやめなければいけなくなった時などにも使われます。

しかし、前述したとおりこれらの意味は殆ど同じであり

それ以上その姿勢を続けられなくなった
と

それ以上その姿勢を続けられない

を両方使ってもそれぞれ伝わる趣旨は殆ど同じです。